# Applying PostSharp aspect via AssemblyInfo

Tags: aop, postsharp, aspect

I want to apply my `VerboseTraceAspect` to my solution, and apply the attribute everywhere except for

1. Getters and setters
2. Any type in `TestProject.Logging.*` and `TestProject.Tracing.*`

I am using the following sample but it does not seem to work. Am I doing this wrong? If so, how should it be done?

Thanks heaps.

```
[assembly: VerboseTraceAspect(AspectPriority = 0, AttributeExclude = true, AttributeTargetTypes = "TestProject.Logging.*|TestProject.Tracing.*")]

[assembly: VerboseTraceAspect(AspectPriority = 1, AttributeExclude = true, AttributeTargetMembers = "regex:get_.*|set_.*")]

[assembly: VerboseTraceAspect(AspectPriority = 2, AttributeTargetTypes = "TestProject.*", 
    AttributeTargetTypeAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public, 
    AttributeTargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public, 
    AttributeTargetElements = MulticastTargets.Method)]
```

Comment: Could you specify what exactly does not seem to work? Is the attribute not applied at all? Is it applied everywhere including getters, setters, Logging, Tracing?

Answer (score 2):

You need to correct the target types expression in the first line where you remove your trace attribute from `TestProject.Logging.*` and `TestProject.Tracing.*`. If you want to specify several options separated with pipeline, then you should use regular expressions syntax.

You also need to use `AttributePriority` instead of `AspectPriority` property. The attribute multicasting is performed before the `AspectPriority` has any effect. It's used later to determine the order in which your aspects will execute.

The "exclude" attributes must have a higher priority value (higher values are processed after lower values).

```
[assembly: VerboseTraceAspect(
    AttributePriority = 1,
    AttributeExclude = true,
    AttributeTargetTypes = @"regex:TestProject\.Logging\..+|TestProject\.Tracing\..+")]

[assembly: VerboseTraceAspect(
    AttributePriority = 2,
    AttributeExclude = true,
    AttributeTargetMembers = "regex:get_.*|set_.*")]

[assembly: VerboseTraceAspect(
    AttributePriority = 0,
    AttributeTargetTypes = "TestProject.*",
    AttributeTargetTypeAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public,
    AttributeTargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public,
    AttributeTargetElements = MulticastTargets.Method)]
```

Comment: Hi Alex thanks for your response. How would I handle Extension Methods? I have added a Method to System.Type which I want to exclude.

Comment: Hi does anyone no how to handle extension methods?

Comment: Just deal with it as with normal static method. For example, if it's in a static class named `MyExtensionMethods`, then that's the class you want to exclude from multicasting.